# Stop refresh page after remote form is loaded via jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div on a page where I load a div from another php page (of the same website) by using the jquery .load() and setTimeout() to refresh it. This div though contains a form with two radio buttons that have random names and id's. After the submit button is pressed the page gets redirected to the form page which contains other options. What I want to do is submit the form without redirecting to the default form page.

p.s. the div containing the form "disappears" after submission and another div with other options appears. I just want it to dissappear from the destination div. I don't have control over the source page and cannot change anything there.

```
<div id="destinationdiv">
//source form that doesn't have id goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delegate a submit handler to the form on page load, even though it won't exist until it is ajax loaded. Since form has no identifiers, will use it's parent element and the form tag as selector

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on('submit', '#destinationdiv form', function() { /* "this" will be the form element*/


    /* serialize all fields for ajax submittal*/
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    /* ajax post data */
    $.post(url, data, function(data) { 
       /* do something with return data, or local html on success here*/
    });

    /* prevent browser default submit*/

    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make your own "submit", by serializing the form (see JQuery's `.serialize()`) and sending it via AJAX (with `$.get()` or `$.post`):

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {

  $.post("pageThatUsesTheFormData.php", $(this).serialize();

  return false;
});
```

(I assume it's a php page that uses the form data but can also be ASP.NET, doesn't matter).

This way the form won't be actually "submitted" as in common HTML sense (that's because of `return false;`), but you can still send the data to the page that will process it.

Use `$.get("url?"+$(this).serialize());` if you have to use GET method instead of POST.

Comment: form has no identifiers and is ajax loaded...better to delagate handler

Comment: There were no identifiers so I used the other method. Thanks anyway!